# Why don't my gallery images display on one line?

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I am currently learning css. I was hoping to create a gallery of 3 images  lined together under a short paragraph on top. However, I am having trouble lining the images on a single line, and scaling them.

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Wardrobe Inspiration </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wardrobe.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color: gainsboro;">
        <div>
        <h1>Welcome to my gallery of ideas for your wardrobe</h1>
        <p1> Get inspired and unleash your inner Coco Chanel! </p1>
        </div>  

        <div>
            <h3>The benefits of a minimalist wardrobe...</h3>
            <div>
             <ul>
                 <li>Gives you additional space in your room</li>
                  <li>Makes it quicker and easier to choose clothes in the morning</li>
                  <li>Helps your style get simpler and more elegant</li>
             </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>

            <div ID="stefets-picture" ID="stefets-picture:hover" class="gallery-item">
                <img src= "minimal1.jpeg">
            </div>

            <div ID="stefets-picture" ID="stefets-picture:hover" class="gallery-item">
                <img src= "minimal2.jpeg">
            </div>

            <div ID="stefets-picture" ID="stefets-picture:hover"class="gallery-item" >
                <img src= "minimal3.jpeg">
            </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="checkout">
                <p>Feel free to check out my</p>
                <a href = "https://www.pinterest.fr/esploratempo/boards/" target="_blank" > Pinterest </a>
            </div>
        </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the associated css:

```
.gallery-item {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.checkout{
    text-align: center
}

p {
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    float: center;
}

#stefets-picture {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

#stefets-picture:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

Where am I going wrong with the gallery? Any help is much much appreciated.

Comment: I strongly suggest abandoning floats altogether. They were a bandage at a time when modern CSS layout mechanisms weren't available. I haven't used them deliberately for many years. Look at `inline-block`, flexbox, and css-grid.

Comment: Also, you should reduce your question to one clear point. Displaying images inline and scaling them are two different things, and there's a lot up there that isn't really relevant. Simple questions get the best answers. Welcome to SO. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Also also, ID values must be unique. An identifier that isn't doesn't identify anything. Use classes (sets of like things) instead, in your markup and in your CSS.

Comment: Also also also, no element can have more than one attribute of the same name. You have elements with multiple ID attributes (and some have apparent CSS  selectors in them, which is incorrect).

Comment: @isherwood thank you for your clarifications! I'll try changing the code the way you suggested. I just started learning html & css very recently so I'm not surprised my code is messy and has lots of misuses. I used float as the course I'm taking teaches that first, but I was suggested to get familiar with flexbox so I'll forget about float I guess! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had added some things and it works for me.

This is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Wardrobe Inspiration </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wardrobe.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color: gainsboro;">
        <div>
        <h1>Welcome to my gallery of ideas for your wardrobe</h1>
        <p1> Get inspired and unleash your inner Coco Chanel! </p1>
        </div>  

        <div>
            <h3>The benefits of a minimalist wardrobe...</h3>
            <div>
             <ul>
                 <li>Gives you additional space in your room</li>
                  <li>Makes it quicker and easier to choose clothes in the morning</li>
                  <li>Helps your style get simpler and more elegant</li>
             </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div id="container" class="container">

            <div ID="stefets-picture" ID="stefets-picture:hover" class="gallery-item">
                <img src= "minimal1.jpeg" class="photo-class">
            </div>

            <div ID="stefets-picture" ID="stefets-picture:hover" class="gallery-item">
                <img src= "minimal2.jpeg" class="photo-class">
            </div>

            <div ID="stefets-picture" ID="stefets-picture:hover"class="gallery-item">
                <img src= "minimal3.jpeg" class="photo-class">
            </div>

        </div>


        <footer>
            <div class="checkout">
                <p>Feel free to check out my</p>
                <a href = "https://www.pinterest.fr/esploratempo/boards/" target="_blank" > Pinterest </a>
            </div>
        </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is CSS

```
.gallery-item {
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.checkout{
    text-align: center
}

p {
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    float: center;
}

#stefets-picture {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

#stefets-picture:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


.photo-class {
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
}
```

This line:

```
.photo-class {
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
}
```

gives you control of the height of your photos. All of them can be different size, but it will scale them to the hight of, in this case, 200px.

Also I have added "container" which will keep things organised and after displaying photos container class with ::after will clear the float and place footer underneath. Hope I halped. Good luck learning HTML and CSS ;)

Answer (score 0):

here is a fix and solution for your page. the Galleries work on mobile view too, responsive size of each image

```css
body {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.gallery-items {
  display: flex;
}

.gallery-item {
  width: 33.33%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.checkout {}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.stefets-picture {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.stefets-picture:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Welcome to my gallery of ideas for your wardrobe</h1>
  <p1> Get inspired and unleash your inner Coco Chanel! </p1>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>The benefits of a minimalist wardrobe...</h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Gives you additional space in your room</li>
      <li>Makes it quicker and easier to choose clothes in the morning</li>
      <li>Helps your style get simpler and more elegant</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-items">

  <div class="stefets-picture gallery-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1">
  </div>

  <div class="stefets-picture gallery-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1">
  </div>

  <div class="stefets-picture gallery-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1">
  </div>

</div>
<footer>
  <div class="checkout">
    <p>
      Feel free to check out my
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.pinterest.fr/esploratempo/boards/" target="_blank"> Pinterest </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```